# React: Is there any way to cache components or prevent redundant HTTP calls with each render

Tags: reactjs, react-router

The simple Code Sandbox below shows that navigating to a component triggers a fresh render.  The React profiler states the components were rendered because they are continually seen for the first time.  I understand this to be the correct React behavior, because each mounting/render generates new method references that triggers the re-rendering.  However, this means that several http requests will be made despite nothing having changed.  Is there any way to keep those requests from being made every time the user navigates to a component?

In the `codesandbox` I've tried using `React.memo` along with `useCallback`, and neither reuse the initial rendering.

Click the `console` tab to see each time the component renders, it makes a fresh ajax call.

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/pstephenwille/react-render-question

Comment: Any update of your issues?

Answer (score -1):

To avoid redundant HTTP calls you have to verify that your origin server does not have updated your local data. If you really want to just fire the HTTP calls once, you can e.g. execute them in your `App` component or pass a state and a callback function down to your `Foo` and `Bar` screen components that will ensure a singular call

Comment: What I’ve said is, that you have to consider, that the data at your backend may have updated. Otherwise you can use the explanation I supplied.

Comment: sure, I understand.  It's really not germane to the question.  Plus, it's an opinion.  If you remove that statement, I'll up vote it.

Comment: It's not an opinion to mention common pitfalls in context. You're question `Is there any way to keep those requests from being made every time the user navigates to a component?` is aiming to save regular calls to the backend. A common pitfall is by sparing initial HTTP calls a frontend gets out of sync with the backend. That's why by experience caching is often not possible. [Stale-while-revalidate cache strategy](https://jerickson.net/four-ways-keep-backend-data-synced-frontend/) And you're free to up- / down vote if a post is helpful for you, but I'll not change a carefully thought answer.